# Confused about Duplicate Record Sets

Tags: duplicate-management, duplicate-matching-rule

I have an Org where we are in the process of cleaning a lot of duplicates. During this process, I noticed some things I never understood about this mechanic and couldn't find any answers in the documentation.

1. There are many old duplicate record set records for duplicates - some are not even duplicates anymore, but the record sets still exist. When are they cleaned up? Do I need to delete them manually?
2. Generally, it seems that you can have a record with duplicates and no duplicate record set and vice versa. How? Why? What's the point of having two separate mechanisms in play, and how do they work? Is this assumption even correct?
3. Who is creating those records? I've seen `Automated Process` but I thought I'd seen those records created by other users.
4. When are those records created? It seems this happens upon updating the record - but I'm not sure.
5. This is an Enterprise Org, and I cannot find the `Duplicate Jobs` anywhere. Is there another precondition for this to show up?
6. I tried to read all the documentation but could not find anything in-depth. Do you have further resources regarding this topic? Or anything that I might have missed?

Please bear with me and provide constructive feedback if my question is considered bad in any form - I would like to improve it. Thanks!

Comment: My colleague stumbled upon a part of one secret. Editing a duplicate record does not seem to yield either duplicate record sets or duplicate record items. Creating a new record that kinda matches your duplicate does yield them and they show up in the report.

Comment: `#5 Duplicate Jobs` - requires Unlimited Edition

Comment: Right! Enterprise is a level below Unlimited. Thanks for pointing that out @cropredy!

Comment: have you found a solution to make the old duplicate record set deleted automatically ?

Comment: @MinhAnh Sadly - no. I now delete them manually or via a script. But what helps is to have a filter in your report that only shows the duplicate record sets where the number of records is greater than one. That way at least the merged records will vanish from the report when done.